# Its better to use a array, set or a dictionary for large number of items?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

My app load two json files one with 27 items(states) and the other with 5.000 items(cities), all items are unique, example of the json:

```
state:{
        "_id": "58c0a61052effb00a396d399",
        "sigla": "AM",
        "descricao": "Amazonas"
}

city:{
      "_id": "5949767555cb9533e09c2932",
      "state": "58c0a6104ace7c56035f7691",
      "nome": "Abadia dos Dourados",
      "ibge": 3100104,
 }
```

I need to execute the following operations:

- search all cities from a state;
- search a state for id;
- search a city for id;
- search a city for name;

Its better to use a array, set or a dictionary for this case?

Comment: 5000 entries is small enough that you could have dictionaries that key each city by `id`/`name`, etc., but this is really what databases are for

Comment: Yes i would rather query your filters to the database instead of downloading everything and search locally

Comment: @J.Doe Even if each city was a kilobyte (they're not, they seem to be around 150), 5000 of them would only be 5 MB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand the below information, you need to understand the *Big O notation*. Briefly, this is the number of steps your algorithm will take, in the worst case, to complete it's task. For example, searching an element into an array will take *n* steps at worst, if the element is into the last position. So, searching an element in the array can be considered O(n). For more references about O notation, look at references in the end of this answer.

Ok, knowing that, now you should select the data structures that execute less steps to complete the task you want it to. This will make your algorithm faster, and in some cases, this difference can be big.

Below are some information of the data structures you asked and their performance according to the Raywenderlich reference:

**Array**

Use array when the order of items matters. Example: contacts sorted by first or last name, a to-do list by date, or other situations when it's critical to find or display data in specific order.

Performance according to Apple's documentation:

1. Creating a Swift Array and an NSArray degrade at roughly the same rate between O(log n) and O(n).
2. Accessing any value at a particular index is at worst O(log n), but should be usually O(1).
3. Searching for an object at an unknown index is at worst O (n (log n)), but will generally be O(n).
4. Inserting or deleting an object is at worst O(n (log n)) but will often be O(1).

Basically, these performance expectations means array are good when you know the index of the object, operating mostly with O(1).

**Dictionary**

Dictionaries are best used when there isn’t a particular order to what you need to store, but the data has meaningful association. Dictionaries use a data structure called hash table, that allows some performance improvements relating to array.

Expected performance for dictionaries, according to Apple documentation are:

1. The performance degradation of getting a single value is guaranteed to be at worst O(log n), but will be often O(1).
2. Insertion and deletion can be as bad as O(n (log n)), but typically will be closer to O(1).

**Set**

A set is a data structure that stores unordered, unique values. Unique is the key word; you won’t be able to add a duplicate.

Apple didn't outline overall expectations for set performance as they did for dictionaries and arrays, so in this case you'll just look at real-world performance.

According to Raywenderlich tests made, the performances of set are:

1. Set creation complexity is around O(n).
2. Adding an object to an NSSet stays near O(1), whereas it can degrade at a rate higher than O(n) with Swift's Set structure.
3. Deleting of an element is around O(1).
4. Searching for an element is around O(1).

---

**In Conclusion**

So, for your case, I would recommend using a dictionary with *id* as key, because most of your searches will use it. This will means, mostly, one step O(1) for the program to find any city in the dictionary. If it was an array, it could take 5000 steps, if you have 5000 cities.

You could also use a set, because internally it uses hash. But, I guess that in set, this advantage would be useful when you search for the instance object city, and not for an attribute in it. For example:

```
let citiesSet = Set()
// add some cities into citiesSet
let city = City()
citiesSet.contains(city) //this search will be O(1)
```

I'm not sure about the above information, but I guess it is how it happens (someone can correct me, if I'm wrong).

For the search of a city by name, it will still takes *n* steps in the dictionary, because the name is not the key. But this is still better than take *n* steps for all operations haha.

You could use another dictionary with name as key, but this data duplication sounds like an extra complication for me, as you would need to guarantee the data is update in both dictionaries. So I wouldn't do that.

The Raywenderlich reference below is great to a better understanding about these structures and their performances. I recommend you to read it.

---

**References:**

[Big O notation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

[Data Structures in Swift - Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123100/collection-data-structures-swift-2)

Comment: `Set` also uses a hash table internally (hence the need for the elements of `Set` to conform to `Hashable`, so a `Set` lookup is _O(1)_ just as a `Dictionary` lookup. Have a look at [Collection Data Structures Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123100/collection-data-structures-swift-2) for more information on the different Swift data structures and their performance.

Comment: Adding on, here is [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/CollectionType/s:FesRxs14CollectionTypeWx9Generator7Element_s9EquatablerS_7indexOfFWxS0_S1__GSqwx5Index_) documentation on `Collection`s having O(1) subscript, and `Set`s are no _acceptations_

Comment: Thanks! I will adjust the answer according.